# Am I able to combine data from many different scraped websites into one csv file?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, export-to-csv

I am working on a scraping project using selenium in python. My goal is to be able to make one .csv file with data from all of the different profiles that I scrape. Currently, my script will scrape one profile, then move one to the next, but it will not remember the data from the first profile after it moves on. Please let me know how I can fix this, and get all the data from every profile into my csv file. Thank you!

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/nzalle/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://directory.bcsp.org/")
count = int(input("Number of Pages to Scrape: "))

body = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//body")
profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

while len(profile_count) < count:   # Get links up to "count"
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    sleep(1)
    profile_count = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@align='right']/a")

for link in profile_count:   # Calling up links
    temp = link.get_attribute('href')   # temp for
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")    # open new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])   # focus new tab
    driver.get(temp)

    # Scrape Code
    Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/div').text or driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/div').text

    IssuedBy = "Board of Certified Safety Professionals"

    CertificationNumber = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[2]').text or driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div[2]').text

    CertfiedSince = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[2]').text or driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[1]/div[2]')

    RecertificationCycleORExperation = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[2]').text or driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div[2]')

    try:
        AccreditedBy = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/div[2]/a').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        AccreditedBy = "N/A"

    try:
        Expires = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/div/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/div[2]').text

    except NoSuchElementException:
        Expires = "N/A"

    Data = [Name + "," + IssuedBy + "," + CertificationNumber + "," + CertfiedSince + "," + RecertificationCycleORExperation + "," + Expires + "," + AccreditedBy + '\n']

    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        h = ["Name", "Issued By", "Certification Number", "Certified Since", "Recertification Cycle/Expiration",
             "Expires", "Accredited By"]
        writer.writerow(h)
        writer.writerow([Data] * len(h))
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
driver.close()
```

Comment: You can store the data in a global variable like list of list OR duct (preferred) and than use something like pandas to get all the data in a csv file. Let me know if you want the code as well

Comment: Hi @KuldeepSinghSidhu! Thank you for your quick response. I would really appreciate it if you could provide the code as well so that I can see it visually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu Any updates on the code?

Comment: Will do in few mins

Answer (score 1):

so `labels` are all the column names I can expect in my csv

you can just go through the websites, update `curr_data` and then append that to `data`

so `curr_data` is a dict and `data` is list of dict(s)

after that, you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to create a data frame out of it and then export to csv

```
labels = ["Name", "Issued By", "Certification Number", "Certified Since", "Recertification Cycle/Expiration",
             "Expires", "Accredited By"]
websites = ['first', 'second', 'third']
data = []
for site in websites:
    curr_data = {'site':site}
    for i in labels: curr_data[i]= ''
    # update data for your websites here
    # Eg :
    # curr_data["Name"] = 'Kuldeep'
    data.append(curr_data)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
csv_location = 'myfile.csv'
df.to_csv(csv_location)
```

Comment: @nzalle let me know if you need more help